# The panel date/time Applet doesn't show the evolution agenda's events

Tags: 11.04, applet, calendar, events

Ubuntu 11.04 Classic desktop Beta 2: When the user click (unrolls) the applet located on the top panel (date/time/weather) doesn't show the evolution calendar events. (It shows just the time and locations)

On the previous Ubuntu's version, to see this (agenda events) was possible, why not now?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the calendar in the second tab of the date & time preferences (which you can access from the item at the bottom of the menu).

Comment: I have same problem but your answer is not helping